# How negate std::is_integral for use in tag dispatch?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I've been playing around with tag dispatch, and the following code works exactly as I expect:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

void impl(std::true_type) { std::cout << "true\n"; }
void impl(std::false_type) { std::cout << "false\n"; }

template<typename T>
void dispatch(T&& val)
{
  impl(std::is_integral<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>());
}

int main()
{
  dispatch(10);    // calls impl(std::true_type)
  dispatch("");    // calls impl(std::false_type)
}
```

But if I want to negate the condition, I'm running into trouble. I thought I could just throw a "`!`" into the code inside `dispatch`,

```
impl(!std::is_integral<T>());    // added "!"
```

but this won't compile.

What do I need to do to get this code to work?

Comment: Did you try `impl(!bool(std::is_integral<T>{}));`?

Comment: `impl(std::is_integral<T>())` should probably be `impl(std::is_integral<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>())` otherwise `int x = 10; dispatch(x);` will call the `std::false_type` overload

Comment: @Simple: Good catch, thanks.  I've updated the post to include this.

Comment: @user1095108: Your expression will have type `bool`. We need an expression that will yield a type that is or inherits from `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe Yes, but they are also both convertible to `bool`, you might get away with a true/false parameter, but yea, I was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You could implement `operator !` for `std::integral_constant` (the underlying type for `true_type` and `false_type`):

```
template <typename T, T value>
inline constexpr std::integral_constant<T, !value>
operator ! (std::integral_constant<T, value>)
{ return {}; }
```

This seems like one of those handy little things that could easily be standardized.

Comment: No it's ok. But shouldn't it be restricted to `T == bool`?

Comment: @Dyp C and C++ have a long history of implicit conversion to bool, so I went more generic. `if(!std::integral_constant<int, 13>())` should behave like `if(!13)`, IMO.

Comment: @DyP No valid reason. `!value` is certainly more readable. I'll steal it.

Comment: It won't work for pointer types (if `T` was a pointer type), but that would lead to a substitution failure. The built-in operator `!` is used [in those cases](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8544c87ba41e02735b7d55dda9229faf-7885f3d27d18134d8479d2ab5250c852). An overload for pointer types might not be appropriate for a template named **integral** _constant, but it could be useful.

Comment: @DyP How does that even compile? [It would appear that particular implementation of `integral_constant` has some non-standard conversion operators](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=df579873d9ef7623bb0008a00701d1bb-7885f3d27d18134d8479d2ab5250c852), [including for bool](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f90497207df3abf82860ae73154fd01e-7885f3d27d18134d8479d2ab5250c852).

Comment: No, the unary `*` requires its operand to have pointer-to-object type [expr.unary.op]/1 (similarly for `!`), which invokes the implicit conversion from `integral_constant<T,..>` to `T`. See [expr]/3 "However, these built-in operators participate in overload
resolution, and as part of that process user-defined conversions will be considered where necessary to convert the operands to types appropriate for the built-in operator"

Comment: I find it dangerous/impolite to override an operator solely on a type you have no ownership of.  As an example of why it is dangerous, if the standard adds their own overrides, your code breaks: as for why it is impolite, operators on a type are effectively part of that types interface, and injecting into another type's interface seems overly presumptuous.

Answer (score 5):

you may instantiate a `std::integral_constant` from a constexpr value like this:

```
 impl(std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_integral<T>::value>());
```

`std::true_type` and `std::false_type` actually aliases to this class. The other way is to introduce a [*metafunction*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/metafunction.html) for this:

```
template <typename T>
struct not_ : std::integral_constant<bool, !T::value> {};
```

and use (call) it:

```
impl(typename not_<std::is_integral<T>>::type());
```

or use the similar from `boost::mpl`

Comment: Why not just `not_<std::is_integral<T>>()`?

Comment: @GManNickG because it is instantiation of the `struct not_` (obviously :), but `impl()` overloaded for `std::integral_constant<bool, Value>`, where is the `Value` can be `true` or `false`. So `not_` is a _metafunction_ and must be "called" by accessing its nested `type`

Comment: @zaufi: Nope. `not_` is convertible to `std::integral_constant` (obviously, since it inherits from it), so going to `type` would be done automatically. I suppose I should have been more direct in my original comment: it's unorthodox to do it the way you are, just use `not_` directly. :) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8e76034e70dbc99cee1e27c983fee8c4-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Answer (score 1):

```
std::false_type negate( std::true_type ) { return {}; }
std::true_type negate( std::false_type ) { return {}; }
impl(negate(std::is_integral<T>()));
```

Or, a bit fancier:

```
template<typename T, T x>
std::integral_constant<T, !x> negate( std::integral_constant<T,x> ) { return {}; }
impl(negate(std::is_integral<T>()));
```

which extends `negate` to work on all `integral_constants`.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::negation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/negation) has been introduced in C++17.